# Null Pointer Exception - Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

I started programming a basic temperature conversion app for android today (still a beginner), and I seem to be getting a NullPointerException and I can't figure out what's causing it. I've tried commenting out the parts of the code that could possibly cause the error but no luck there. When I run the app on my android device over ADB, the app crashes on start-up.

It is a work in progress, so please ignore any unfinished parts (unless that's what's causing the problem). Here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String array_spinner1[];
    private String array_spinner2[];
    private EditText input1;
    private EditText input2;
    Spinner topSpinner;
    Spinner bottomSpinner;
    String topSpinnerVal;
    String bottomSpinnerVal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        topSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input1Sp);
        bottomSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input2Sp);
        topSpinnerVal = topSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        bottomSpinnerVal = bottomSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        array_spinner1=new String[3];
        array_spinner1[0]="Celsius";
        array_spinner1[1]="Fahrenheit";
        array_spinner1[2]="Kelvin";
        array_spinner2=new String[3];
        array_spinner2[0]="Celsius";
        array_spinner2[1]="Fahrenheit";
        array_spinner2[2]="Kelvin";
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner2);
        topSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        bottomSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1TB);
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2TB);
    }

    public void onClick(View button) {
        Double valTop = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
        Double valBottom = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
        switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.topToBottomBt:
            if (input1.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Requested conversion is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
            }
            if (topSpinnerVal.equals("Celsius")) {
                if (bottomSpinnerVal.equals("Celsius")) {

                }
            }
        case R.id.bottomToTopBt:

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

The logcat log in Eclipse says the following:

```
01-05 00:01:18.687: D/AndroidRuntime(22472): Shutting down VM
01-05 00:01:18.687: W/dalvikvm(22472): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41e23700)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.tumblr.nocturnalparasites.temperatureconversion/com.tumblr.nocturnalparasites.temperatureconversion.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5287)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at com.tumblr.nocturnalparasites.temperatureconversion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5201)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
01-05 00:01:18.687: E/AndroidRuntime(22472):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: And right *after that* it tells you exactly what line the problem is on.

Comment: Please post the COMPLETE LogCat output.

Comment: @BrianRoach It doesn't have the line number in the log anywhere.

Comment: I see line 30 as a potential culprit...I don't know what line 30 *is*, but the Logcat does list what line it occurred on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. It was with the topSpinnerVal and bottomSpinnerVal strings; I was trying to get the value from the spinners before I assigned adapters to them. I instead moved the string assignments to the onClick method, which would be run after the onCreate method.

Here is the working code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private String array_spinner1[];
    private String array_spinner2[];
    private EditText input1;
    private EditText input2;
    Spinner topSpinner;
    Spinner bottomSpinner;
    String topSpinnerVal;
    String bottomSpinnerVal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        topSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input1Sp);
        bottomSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input2Sp);
        array_spinner1=new String[3];
        array_spinner1[0]="Celsius";
        array_spinner1[1]="Fahrenheit";
        array_spinner1[2]="Kelvin";
        array_spinner2=new String[3];
        array_spinner2[0]="Celsius";
        array_spinner2[1]="Fahrenheit";
        array_spinner2[2]="Kelvin";
        ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_spinner2);
        topSpinner.setAdapter(adapter1);
        bottomSpinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1TB);
        input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2TB);
    }

    public void onClick(View button) {
        topSpinnerVal = topSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        bottomSpinnerVal = bottomSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Double valTop = Double.parseDouble(input1.getText().toString());
        Double valBottom = Double.parseDouble(input2.getText().toString());
        switch (button.getId()) {
        case R.id.topToBottomBt:
            if (input1.getText().length() == 0){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Requested conversion is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
            }
            if (topSpinnerVal.equals("Celsius")) {
                if (bottomSpinnerVal.equals("Celsius")) {

                }
            }
        case R.id.bottomToTopBt:

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thank you to the users that answered.

Answer (score 1):

Move all this inside `onCreate` after setContentView

```
Spinner topSpinner;
Spinner bottomSpinner;
String topSpinnerVal; 
String bottomSpinnerVal;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
topSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input1Sp);
bottomSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input2Sp);
topSpinnerVal = topSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
bottomSpinnerVal = bottomSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

`findViewById` looks for a view with the id mentioned in the current inflated layout. So first you need to set the content of the layout to the activity and then initialize your views.

Edit:

You also have

```
 Spinner s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input1Sp);
 Spinner s2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input2Sp);
```

Why do you require the above when you already have the below

```
topSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input1Sp);
bottomSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input2Sp);
```

Set the adapter to `topSpinner` and `bottomSpinner`

Also

```
if (topSpinnerVal == "Celsius") {
```

Should be

```
if (topSpinnerVal.equals("Celsius")) {
```

Use `.equals` to compare strings. Similarly use .equals to compare strings in other places as well

Comment: @user2974881 you can do as suggested above since it is declared as instance variables.

Comment: I deleted the comment. I didn't notice the definition outside of onCreate until right after I posted the comment.

Comment: That did not help. It still crashes and gives me the same error.

Comment: @user2974881 that does help. for further help post the complete stack trace by re running your app. That was one mistake. There might be more.

Comment: @user2974881 check my edit. there are few more errors. Probably more and if you need more help post the logcat

Comment: I have uploaded the complete log. Take a look.

Comment: @user2974881 what is Line 30 pls?

Comment: I also updated the code.

Comment: @user2974881 Line 30 `MainActivity.java` is null. SO inidcate which line it is

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44541/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-user2974881)

Comment: Sorry for being late, I was working on the problem. But I figured it out (answer below).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take a look at @Raghunandan advices, all those you need. 
Then, check your logcat to check the line a find out what view is producing the error, or do a step by step debug (if you dont know how, follow this eclipse help page: [http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-stepping.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-stepping.htm)

One or more of your views is making it crash, since you are not checking if they are null after findViewById, before using the view.

When you find the view that produces the error, look for it in your layout, in the exact file that is being loaded for the device size and config that you are using for testing, and make sure that id is there. (Eclipse will not mark the error if that id is in any file in the project, but if it is not in the correct file, you willl have this runtime error)